# redirect TLS 1.0 to a page from website using apache

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, tls1.0

I have a website **foo.com** and I need to redirect all the connections from browsers with TLS 1.0 to **foo.com/specific-page**. I checked the [Apache documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Web_Servers.html#s1-The_Apache_HTTP_Server) and I can disable the TLS protocol, but there is any way to force a redirect to a specific page using apache configuration?
In a first attempt I tried to make the redirect using code on the application using javascript but since this is client side, this is not a real blocker of TLS 1.0.
The second approach was on netscaler but since the page that I want to redirect is on the same domain, the netscaler can't block TLS 1.0 and redirect to a sub page inside the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

See this gist:
https://gist.github.com/SamuelChristie/13a2a29e74c189bcfd9b#apache

> Apache's **mod_ssl** offers environmental variables which can provide details related to the current SSL/TLS connection. Adding the following lines to your conf file (be sure you are using mod_headers) will inject two new headers into the incoming request. You can then use `X-SSL-Protocol` in your Perl, PHP, Python, etc. to assess whether or not a warning should be displayed.
>
> ```
> SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
> RequestHeader set X-SSL-Protocol %{SSL_PROTOCOL}s
> RequestHeader set X-SSL-Cipher %{SSL_CIPHER}s
> ```
>
> Sample PHP to read the TLS version (as with rails, PHP/CGI also changes the header name):
>
> ```
> $tlsversion = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_SSL_PROTOCOL"];
> ```

Even simpler with nginx:

```
if ($ssl_protocol != "TLSv1.2") {
    return 302 https://example.com/outdated-tls.html;
}
```

Comment: I know that with nginx is even simpler. however, I'm only using Apache.
The question is there is any configuration on the apache itself that allows this feature